# in GNU Emacs on OSX, a key binding to activate Mavericks full-screen mode?

Tags: macos, emacs, fullscreen, osx-mavericks, aquamacs

In GNU Emacs on OSX, is it possible to assign key binding stroke to activate Mavericks full-screen mode? I see that there is a function `toggle-maxframe`, but this merely maximizes the frame, and doesn't activate Mavericks' true full-screen mode.

Is it possible to assign a key binding to this action so I can use Emacs truly mouse-free, without having to use my mouse to click the full-screen button?

[image: full-screen button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Emacs 24.4 (released on 2014-10-20), there is a function called `toggle-frame-fullscreen` that's bound to <kbd>F11</kbd> by default.

---

For earlier versions of Emacs, [there is a little function over at EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc28):

```lisp
(defun toggle-fullscreen ()
  "Toggle full screen"
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter
     nil 'fullscreen
     (when (not (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)) 'fullboth)))
```